# Why does Processing draw my sine wave in a samply way?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to get Processing to draw a sine wave. However, it appears like a badly sampled version of a sine wave on the output. Do I need to replace the shape with a series of lines, or is there another solution?

I've tried casting the variable to a float, and changing `c++` to `c += 1`.

```java
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  beginShape();
  translate(0, 100);
  for (int c = 0; c <= width; c += 1)
  {
    vertex(c, (float) 100 * sin(c / 50));
  }
  endShape();
```

I expect that it traverses the window pixel-by-pixel, creating a smooth shape.
What I actually get is what appears to be sampled, as shown here.

Quantized sine wave

[image]

Comment: Yep. It definitely is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

> ```
> c / 50
> ```

is an integral division. The result is an integral value. If `0 <= c < 50`, then the result is 0, if `50 <= c < 100` then the result 1.

To do a floating point division, with a floating point result, on of the 2 values has to be floating point (e.g. `c / 50.0`).

Change the expression to solve the issue:

```java
vertex(c, 100.0 * sin((float)c / 50.0));
```

[image]